How to effectively monitor process creation using python in Windows ? Currently missing out short lived processes
My aim: I have been trying to continuously monitor process creation using python (without a lot of pre-requisites) but I am not able to capture short lived processes. I want this python script to run in the background and want to be able to see all processes that are created while this process is running (even the ones that are created and deleted quickly. Something similar to procmon).
I have tries using psutil and wmi in python but still was not able to capture all process creations. It still misses a few processes.
The methods I have tried are as follows:

I tried psutil - Doesn't work for short lived processes (These processes are created and deleted before an iteration completes).
Code snippet:

while True:
   for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
      <Perform operations>


Tried wmi - Also doesn't work for short lived processes (These processes are created and deleted before an iteration completes).

    c = wmi.WMI()
    # Monitor creation of processes
    watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for(raw_wql="SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'")
    
    while True:
        new_event = watcher()
        print(new_event.Caption)

Method that I am going to try (last resort).
3. I am yet to turn on 'Audit Process Creation' and try reading the event logs.
I wanted this code to work without much pre-requisites therefore this is my last resort.
There are similar questions but none of them answers the question.

How to monitor process program execution in windows

Windows real time process creation monitor in python


The following are my doubts.

Is there any other way to do this in python?
If there is no way to do this in python, will I have to use any other language to be successful in this?


How about reducing the delay? watcher = c.watch_for (   notification_type="Creation",   wmi_class="Win32_Process",   delay_secs=0.01,   Name='calc.exe' )

Still missing out on short lived processes. :(
